# How to change CUDA version

Tags: opencv, cuda, caffe

I met this error when compiling a modified caffe version.

`OpenCV static library was compiled with CUDA 7.5 support. Please, use the same version or rebuild OpenCV with CUDA 8.0`

I have some old code may not compatible with CUDA8.0, so I want to change my cuda version for this error.

I modified my ~/.bash_profile like this

```
# export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64/
# export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/usr/local/cuda-7.5/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/cuda-7.5/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/
```

But it did't work. Still the same error. What should I do?

Comment: how are you compiling? cmake?

Comment: you need to rebuild opencv with cuda 8.0 there is no other way!

Comment: @BNT Yes, cmake.

Comment: @BalajiR Really? Can't I just change the cuda version? It seems possible according to the error information.

Comment: @baNv can you post your cmake config?

Comment: @BNT I'm not sure which file do you want... Do you mean CMakeLists.txt?
 Here is the link of the caffe version I am working on. https://github.com/varunjampani/video_prop_networks

Comment: I had a same problem. My solution is changing the bash file like above and remove the CMakeCache.txt

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Change your CUDA soft link to point on your desired CUDA version. For example:

> ll /usr/local/cuda
> lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 19 Sep 06  2017 /usr/local/cuda -> /usr/local/cuda-8.0/

Simply relink it with

Update:
If the symlink already exists, use this other command:

```
[jalal@goku ~]$ ls /usr/local/cuda
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 20 Sep 14 08:03 /usr/local/cuda -> /usr/local/cuda-10.2

[jalal@goku ~]$ sudo ln -sfT /usr/local/cuda/cuda-11.1/ /usr/local/cuda
[jalal@goku ~]$ ls /usr/local/cuda
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 26 Sep 14 13:25 /usr/local/cuda -> /usr/local/cuda/cuda-11.1/
```

> ln -s /usr/local/cuda-7.5 /usr/local/cuda

(With the proper installation location)

Comment: If you use the `ln -s` command, it will fail if the symlink already exists.  So remove the old symlink with a simple `sudo rm /usr/local/cuda`.  (As always, be very careful with your paths when using `sudo rm`!)

Comment: I don't have the sudo permission, and got the following error ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘/usr/local/cuda-10.0/cuda-8.0’: Permission denied

Comment: You can also use `sudo ln -sf` to create OR update the symlink if it already exists.  Then you won't need the `rm` command.

Comment: This doesn't work for me - after a reboot, the symlink is correct, but `nvidia-smi` gives me the wrong version.

Comment: @ChrisAnderson `nvidia-smi` is showing the cuda version for driver API. Use `nvcc --version` to find out cuda version. See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53422407/different-cuda-versions-shown-by-nvcc-and-nvidia-smi

Comment: Oddly `sudo ln -sf` doesn't work for me (on an Ubuntu 20.04 based distro, ln version 8.30), I agree it should do... Had no effect. Cannot reproduce in my own namespace without sudo...

Comment: @LouisMaddox check the edits I made to the post

Comment: Please remember to update `PATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variables after doing this as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63737492/opencv-claims-to-find-wrong-cuda-version/75080353#75080353).

Comment: This should be avoided in favour of using the safer update-alternatives package as the answer by [@w-t](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7223954/w-t) indicates.

Answer (score 34):

Perhaps cleaner:

```
sudo update-alternatives --display cuda

sudo update-alternatives --config cuda
```

Comment: This is the best answer. Simple commands, no need to install anything else, & reversible.

Comment: This is a safer and more standard procedure. Less manual intervention at the command line leads to fewer errors in running specific versions of programs. Just use it consistently to find out what is selected and in what mode (auto goes to the option with the highest priority) and to change it manually if you need to. That way the version of cuda will change at the system level without setting symlinks by hand.

Comment: @PabloAdames This does nothing for me? sudo update-alternatives --display nvcc
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for nvcc
There are definitely multiple nvcc's installed

Comment: @illan This might happen if you have not configured update-alternatives to track multiple versions of the program, in the case discussed here we want to manage multiple versions of a program called `cuda`. You would have to first install the alternatives that refer to different executable binaries. An example, `sudo update-alternatives --install </path/to/all/alternative_links> <name_of_managed_program> /path/to/executable <priority_number>`. For this case, name_of_managed_program is `cuda`. Do that for the two or more binaries. Use the same path to the alternative_links.

Answer (score 13):

Maybe a bit late, but I thought it might still be helpful for anyone who comes across this question. I wrote a simple bash script for switching to a different version of CUDA *within the current bash session*: https://github.com/phohenecker/switch-cuda

Comment: Great thank! Your toolkit is really useful. For the most of time, I have no access to the sudo authority.

Comment: best answer imo. It doesn't even need sudo authority to perform

Answer (score 11):

This solution explains how you can have **multiple different cuda versions installed**, i.e. 10.2, 11.3 and 11.6 and switch between them. It's an extension of @w.t and makes use of `update-alternatives`.

Afaik, after cuda 11.x the installations on Ubuntu 20.04 cuda installations will be added to the `update-alternatives` maintenance automatically.

Let's say you installed cuda 10.2, cuda 11.3 and cuda 11.6 (following the official nvidia installation guide: https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html). They will all reside in:

```
/usr/local/cuda-10.2/...
/usr/local/cuda-11.3/...
/usr/local/cuda-11.6/...
```

Your `update-alternatives` will have two entries:

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --query cuda
...
/usr/local/cuda-11-3 - priority 113
/usr/local/cuda-11-6 - priority 116
```

**Solution 1**: If you want to make use of the `update-alternatives` make sure that your cuda **symbolic link** points to `/etc/alternatives/cuda`.

```
# Change the symbolic link target.
$ sudo ln -sfT /etc/alternatives/cuda /usr/local/cuda
```

```
# Check the path.
$ ll /usr/local/cuda

lrwxrwrwrwx 1 root root /usr/local/cuda -> /etc/alternatives/cuda/
```

Now, all that is left is to make sure `/etc/alternatives/cuda` points to the version you want to use, e.g. 11.3.

You can make that update with:

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --config cuda
```

and follow the instructions to change the version.

Check the path:

```
$ ll /etc/alternatives/cuda

lrwrwrwrwx root root /etc/alternatives -> /usr/local/cuda-11.3
```

almost done.

**And always make sure to load the correct library `PATHs` in your `~/.bashrc`.**

**Solution 2:**
Directly set your `/usr/local/cuda` symbolic link to the correct version.

```
$ ln -sfT /usr/local/cuda-11.3 /usr/local/cuda
```

Reboot your machine and double check everything is set properly:

```
$ nvcc -V

nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2021 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Mon_May3 19:15:14_PDT_2021
Cuda compilation tools, release 11.3 V11.3.109
Build cuda 11.3.r11.3/compiler.29920130_0
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem finally.

Modifying ~/.bash_profile to change the path to CUDA is the correct way. But when you changed the file, you need to **relaunch the bash**.

Simply `source ~/.bash_profile` won't work. Because `source` will only append the content in the file to the already existed path rather than cover it.